# Windows Phone 7.5 People Tile

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I know that Windows Phone 7.5 has the ability to store contacts in the phone itself. I was wondering if there is a way to modify / extend the people tile so that I can add an option to save the contact to phone instead?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know from experience as a Windows Phone user and developer, a Contact can be saved to any linked account but not to a generic storage location on the phone. Contacts can be imported from the SIM card, but not saved to it. Contacts that appear to be stored on the phone are actually synced with a linked account (i.e. Hotmail, Google, etc). The People tile/hub aggregates Contact data from all linked accounts.

If you want to programmatically add a contact to the phone, you can use the **SaveContactTask** from the **Microsoft.Phone.Tasks** namespace.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

SaveContactTask _saveContactTask;

void SaveContact()
{
    _saveContactTask = new SaveContactTask();
    _saveContactTask.Completed += 
    new EventHandler<SaveContactResult>(SaveContactTask_Completed);

    try
    {
         saveContactTask.FirstName = "John";
         saveContactTask.LastName = "Doe";
         saveContactTask.MobilePhone = "2125551212";

         saveContactTask.Show();
    }
    catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.");
    }
}

void SaveContactTask_Completed(object sender, SaveContactResult e)
{
    switch (e.TaskResult)
    {
        case TaskResult.OK:
            MessageBox.Show("Contact saved successfully.");
            break;
        case TaskResult.Cancel:
            MessageBox.Show("Contact save cancelled.");
            break;
        case TaskResult.None:
            MessageBox.Show("Contact could not be saved.");
            break;
    }
}
```

The official "How To" documentation can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394013(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The contacts are stored by default to the phone itself. It is just synced to your windows live/google/any other account you like to!